# forward Request parameters to custom 404 page using ErrorDocument in apache?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-404

Is there a way to have the request parameters "forward on" to the custom error file in apache much like [QSA] does on rewrite rules?

if i send in www.foo.com/doesnotexist?bar=true

and i have this in vhost:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /customerrorpage
```

then it would call customerrorpage with:

```
customerrorpage?bar=true
```

Comment: I can confirm that Richard's suggestion works great. Please accept his answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this is really old question, but it hasn't been answered and so in case someone else is searching the site for the answer I'll share what I know.

The Apache [2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/custom-error.html) ErrorDocument page says that when you have a Custom Error page which is a local page then a number of environment vars will be set which can be read from your customer error handler.  One of the vars is REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING which will contain the query string that the original page had.  So in your example the REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING would contain 'bar=true'.