# Forward query string with ErrorDocument in apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

I'm trying forward to another host when error occurs. I have this, and works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.com.
    ServerAlias test.com

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse /  http://127.0.0.1:8080/

    RewriteEngine on

    ErrorDocument 503 /503/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/503/$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://other.host.com/

</VirtualHost>
```

Now, when I have this URL: `http://test.com/path/?param1=val1&param2=val2` and when 503 error ocurrs, I want redirect to new URL: `http://other.host.com/path/?param1=val1&param2=val2`.

It is possible forward **/path/?param1=val1&param2=val2** to new host?

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19962787/rewrite-url-after-redirecting-404-error-htaccess) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7956451/forward-request-parameters-to-custom-404-page-using-errordocument-in-apache), but it is not exactly my problem.

PS: I'm running a java application, not a php application

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since Apache 2.4.13, ErrorDocument can also use expression, so:

```
ErrorDocument 503 http://other.host.com/%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}
ProxyErrorOverride on
```

Comment: Thanks @julp, this works! I didn't add `ProxyErrorOverride on` and worked too. I have **upgraded apache to 2.4.20**. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Tested in shell script CGI and PHP on Apache 2.2

In shell script CGI, dump the **/bin/env** vars and grep `REQUEST_URI`,

In PHP, ret `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

This tip works for keep query string from httpd.conf settings redirected.

```
ErrorDocument 401 /errCode/401.html
```